# How Do I acces a class from my Main Form?

Tags: c#

Im new to C# infact somedays past only.I got a project from universty so I though os using c#.

What Im doing in this case is **reading text messages from a cell phone and then putting them in a text file.**
I learnt that I have to make a class for writing a File so I did and added that Class to My Form.Now I want to access and send string to that class to write it in a Text File.
But I dont know how to.If anyone could help me directly then I can send him my code or If some1 can send me some guide links I will be Happy.

Thanks xA

Comment: You will likely get more detailed help if you post a copy of your source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot easier. Let's say you have your form and you add a textbox and a button. Double click the button to get the click event and make it look like this.

```
private void button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\File.txt", textBox1.Text);
}
```

This will call the WriteAllText method of the already written File class that you can call directly. The text that is written to the file is in the textBox1.Text property. There's a lot to fill out here but this is the simplest thing that works.